# How do I use the google sheets api v4?

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to switch to the new google spreadsheets API v4 in my android studio app. I am trying to load the data from the URL but the program doesn't find the credentials JSON and I do not know where to put it so the program will see it.

I used the code from the google spreadsheets v4 quickstart github....

The error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /credential.json (No such file or directory)
```

The code:

```
package com.example.sheetsapi;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credential.json";
    static String val = "";
    TextView text;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = findViewById(R.id.txt);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

        try {
            doShit();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                text.setText(val);
            }
        });
    }

    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    public static void doShit() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport();
        final String spreadsheetId = "1HljdyhGauam-1WYa_C1ho2KOQMUrbGUuR3s5OEU8XtE";
        final String range = "Sheet1!A2:A2";
        Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
            val = "No data found.";
        } else {
            for (List row : values) {
                Log.d("mss", "%s, %s\n" + row.get(0) + row.get(1));
                val = (String) row.get(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The image of the project directory: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnI0c.png)

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create assets folder in the project and add the credentials.json (check the attached screenshot) file in it and then access it using this code :

```
InputStream in = getActivity().getAssets().open("credentials.json");
if (in == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: ");
}
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(new GsonFactory(), new InputStreamReader(in));
```